# Resharper code cleanup and blank lines

Tags: visual-studio-2008, resharper

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace {
   <-- blank line
   public class MyClass {
      <-- blank line 
      public void MyMethod1() {
         //something
      }
      <-- blank line
      public void MyMethod2() {
         //something
      }
   }
}
```

When using Code Cleanup option? Currently it's doing like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace{  
   public class MyClass {
      public void MyMethod1() {
         //something
      }

      public void MyMethod2() {
         //something
      }
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance,

André Carlucci

Comment: You can vote for this feature at: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-74903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion you can not do this with the latest ReSharper (4.5.1).
I know the options of the ReSharper very well, but I am not aware of anything that would format the code in a way you'd like.
You are looking for something like "blank lines inside namespace" or "blank lines inside class", which does not exist as an option.

Answer (score 0):

The preferences allow you to configure blank lines between elements of the same kind e.g., method to method spacing. I can't see how to add lines between say the namespace and class.

Options > C# > Formatting Style > Blank Lines

Comment: I think that there is no such option ... I doubt that R# can do what andrecarlucci wants.